# port channel delay coming up <> linux config

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, bonding, lacp

after our 5k switch reboots, due to many configured vlans, LACP/port channels take some time to come up.  seems to be a serial process, and if vlans are at bottom of this list, it takes some time - more than 2 minutes in some cases.

our physical linux servers have the bond config below to wait to send traffic, after we get notification that nic is connected (which does not mean port channel is active)...

```
DEVICE=bond1
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=250 use_carrier=1 updelay=120000 downdelay=500"
MTU=9000
```

linux server waits 2 min (120000 milliseconds), but then can send traffic down this path, which then falls into a back hole.

the question is - is there any config to add (or remove) to insure portchannel is actually up, before sending traffic down this path?

Comment: You could see if it's possible to use LACP with ARP monitoring (arp_interval=,arp_ip_target=) instead of  mii monitoring (miimon=). That's a suggestion for you to look there, I don't know if that makes much sense. ARP would validate data can go beyond the switch but thus requires to have some reliable peers.